# How do I tell PyCharm where to find the actual location of my source code and imports

Tags: python, pycharm

How do I tell PyCharm where to find my python source code

In the image below, python is open at a project level because I prefer having access to proto files aswell as the source code

But, PyCharm highlights my import statements because it is searching for the module `nodes_pb2` at the project source

But I want it to search in `src/` folder, How do I do that
[image: the problem]

Here is my run configuration

I am running `UnrealFlow` as a python module from the `src/` directory
[image: my pycharm run config]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Inside pycharm click into File -> Settings -> Project: Your Project Name -> Project Structure.

Set the `src` folder as the `Source Folder`. There are also another types of folders that you may use in your project, like tests, excluded, etc.

Answer (score 0):

Right-Click on `src` folder and select "Mark Directory as"/"Sources Root". This will only work within PyCharm though - not from the command line.